# React function with parameters inside Component/Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component

I just used a library called `react-axios` where a function is supplied inside of a component in the following way:

```
<Get url="/api/user" params={{id: "12345"}}>
{(parameters) => {
 //some callback with the parameters
}}
</Get>
```

As I have never seen this syntax before and always passed functions with props, I am curious:

- How is this type of function-specification called in React?
- How can a Component be implemented like this?
- Does it also work with function-components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How is this type of function-specification called in React?

The pattern that you suggest in your questions is called render props pattern

- How can a Component be implemented like this?

A very basic implementation can be somethinng like below

```
    function Get(props) {
       const [params, setParams] = useState({}); 
       ...
       return (
        <div>{props.children(params)}</div>
       )
    }
```

- Does it also work with function-components?

Yes it can be writen for functional components as well as class components